# SQL - Count without grouping

Tags: sql, ms-access

Since 3 hours I am trying to count different columns without grouping them.
I tried it with join or sub-select queries, but as I am new in SQL, I did not solve how to do it.

So here is my SQL query:

```
SELECT [Destination ID], 
       [ProjectID], 
       [Campaign ProjectId]
FROM Raw_Data;
```

How can I count the Destination ID, Project ID and the Campaign Project ID in one SQL Query and also show every ID in the Table.

Here one example, how the output should look like:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2LLDL.png)

I am using MS Access.

It would be great, if some could help me.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your question is very hard to understand. Maybe because your are talking about technics ("count without grouping") instead of showing us what result you are after. Show some sample records and expected result and we will gladly help.

Comment: "Every ID"? Both Destination ID, Project id and Campaign ProjectId? Show us sample table data, and the expected result!

Comment: From my understanding of the question, if you just want to count them use `SELECT count(*) FROM Raw_Data;`

Comment: What you want to do may be a use for OLAP functions.  What variant of SQL is this for?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Also: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: Are you looking for `count(distinct Column_Name)` ?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I edited my questions and added a Screenshot. In the answer below, the query is exactly what I wanted. But there the problem is, that the query is not working properly on my computer, because I needs to much ressources. Perhaps you have an "slimmer" query?

Answer (score 1):

You could try this, if I understood you right:

```
SELECT 
    [Destination ID], 
    (SELECT COUNT([Destination ID]) 
        FROM Raw_Data AS T2 
        WHERE T2.[Destination ID] = T1.[Destination ID]) AS DestCount,
    [ProjectID], 
    (SELECT COUNT([ProjectID]) 
        FROM Raw_Data AS T3 
        WHERE T3.[ProjectID] = T1.[ProjectID]) AS ProjectCount,
    [Campaign ProjectId],
    (SELECT COUNT([Campaign ProjectId]) 
        FROM Raw_Data AS T4 
        WHERE T4.[Campaign ProjectId] = T1.[Campaign ProjectId]) AS CampaignCount 
FROM Raw_Data AS T1;
```

**EDIT**

With newer Access versions you could try:

```
SELECT 
    T1.[Destination ID], 
    T2.[DestCount],
    T1.[ProjectID], 
    T3.[ProjectCount],
    T1.[Campaign ProjectId],
    T4.[CampaignCount] 
FROM (((Raw_Data AS T1 
        INNER JOIN 
        (
        SELECT [Destination ID], COUNT([Destination ID]) AS DestCount 
        FROM Raw_Data 
        GROUP BY [Destination ID]
        ) 
        AS T2 ON 
        T1.[Destination ID] = T2.[Destination ID])
        INNER JOIN 
        (
        SELECT [ProjectID], COUNT([ProjectID]) AS ProjectCount
        FROM Raw_Data
        GROUP BY [ProjectID]
        )
        AS T3
        ON T1.[ProjectID] = T3.[ProjectID])
        INNER JOIN 
        (
        SELECT [Campaign ProjectID], COUNT([Campaign ProjectID]) AS CampaignCount
        FROM Raw_Data
        GROUP BY [Campaign ProjectID]
        )
        AS T4
        ON T1.[Campaign ProjectID] = T4.[Campaign ProjectID])
```

I can't test this on newer Access versions, just read that this could work.

Comment: Thanks a lot Nik Bo. This is exactly what I need. But my table is very big and the query took ages. Is there also a other solution possible. Perhaps a more resource-saving query.

Comment: Which MS Access Version do you use?

Comment: @Peter Added a second SQL query. Maybe this work for you and faster. As I write, I can't test this my self.

Comment: @Peter Nice to hear that this helped you. [You can accept the correct answer to close this question.](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)